# Getting Adjusted fontSize after Autoshrink in Swift

Tags: swift, font-size, shrink

I am having trouble getting the font size of a label after the font autoshrinks to fit the width of the label bounds. Inside the user interface, I've set the Autoshrink capability to 'Minimum Font Size' of 9.0. The original font size is set at 17.0. Here is the method I used to get the fontSize:

```
labels.font.pointSize
```

However, even though the label has autoshrunk to say 12.0, the method still gives back 17.0.

Is there any other way to get the current 'autoshrunk' font size?